# How to position the Android Text Selection menu

Tags: android

I have some EditText controls placed within a linear layout in my main.xml file. Whenever you click to select text, the Android default text selection menu appears at the top and displaces the contents within the layout. How do you allow the text selection menu to still appear, but NOT affect the layout of the elements within your view? Specifically, I'd like to control the position of where Text Selection menu appears on the screen.

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
      <EditText

            android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"      
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="26sp"      
         android:textSize="8sp"      
                android:text="save"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code for more detail

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn it's up